# Highly customized map style

Tags: maps, gps, openstreetmap, google-maps

I'm looking into creating a highly customized map. I'd like the map to look similar to something like this: http://cartography.oregonstate.edu/CrinkledWatercolor.html or sort of 16 bit-ish like this: https://youtu.be/F10vCPorUpk?t=252

I'd also like the perspective to be 3rd person sort of like Pokemon GO.

I looked into doing something like this with Google Maps API map styles but it looks like you're limited to a single fill color with no details so that isn't really an option.

Is there a way where I can use my GPS location and a radius parameter to send to some API like google maps to just get a bunch of raw polygon data to create the outline of everything on a map and do a sort of custom rendering of the graphics on the device?

Also, I was looking into OpenStreetMap. It seems like this might be more customizable. Problem with that is a lot of their documentation seems outdated. maperitive also seems like it could be helpful.

I would appreciate any advice as to the best approach or at least a good approach to creating something like this. I'm open to using any library in any programming language mobile or web based.

Comment: Did you contact the people responsible for those which you liked, and ask them how they did it?